# How to integrate $\int^\infty_{0} e^{-xy-x}dx$?

Tags: calculus

How to integrate
$$ \int^\infty_{0} e^{-xy-x}dx$$
where $y$ is a constant?

Integration by parts doesn't work. I can't figure out other ways.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may be more obvious if you rewrite the integrand as
$$ \int_0^\infty e^{-x(y+1)} dx.$$
If the letter $y$ confuses, it may be helpful to think about the generic antiderivative
$$ \int e^{ax} dx$$
for any constant $a$. One doesn't need integration by parts, as I suspect you already know the antiderivative. (If not, then you could perform a $u$-substitution).

Answer (score 3):

The integral can be rewritten as 
$$
I = \int_0^\infty e^{-ax}dx
$$
where $a=y+1$. This is an improper integral, so you need to check if (when) it converges:

So
$$
I = \int_0^\infty e^{-ax}dx = \lim_{b\to\infty}\left[-\frac{e^{-ax}}{a}\right]_{0}^{b}=
\lim_{b\to\infty}
\left(-\frac{e^{-ab}}{a}+\frac{1}{a}\right)
$$
Now, you need to check if the above limit exists.
If $a\leq0\iff y\leq-1$ the limit diverges and so does the integral. Otherwise, i.e., when $a>0\iff y>-1$, it converges to $\frac{1}{a}=\frac{1}{y+1}$.